# SQL WHERE User.Identity.Name Using Parameters

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a DetailsView to show only the records in my database that meet the criteria of fulfiling the QueryString value which I have prescribed, and are equal to the current User.Identity.Name authenticated user.

I have gotten this far but I don't know what I am doing wrong as the page seems to be blank still when I pass a value I know is logical and meets both criteria above in the Query String at runtime.

I'll provide you with the relevant snippets rather than posting the full DetailsView code:

SQL Select Command:

```
SELECT * FROM [Events] WHERE ([EventID] = ?) AND (CreatedBy = @MemberName)
```

SELECT Parameters:

```
<SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="EventID" QueryStringField="ID" 
                Type="Int32" />
        <asp:parameter name="MemberName" type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
```

And finally the Code Behind to associate User.Identity.Name with the MemberName parameter:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs)
        e.Command.Parameters(1).Value = Me.User.Identity.Name
End Sub
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that Me.User.Identity.Name is not empty?

Comment: Have you tried making your SelectCommand a little more internally consistent? Using "@" notation on both params might help: `SELECT * FROM [Events] WHERE ([EventID] = @EventID) AND (CreatedBy = @MemberName)`